# mixing redis actioncontroller::live - rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, chat

I am using for the first time `redis` to put chat functionality in my rails app, following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live)

I have in my javascript`

```
$(document).ready ->
  source = new EventSource('/messages/events')
  source.addEventListener 'messages.create', (e) ->
    message = $.parseJSON(e.data).message
    console.log(message)
    $(".chat-messages").append "#some code"
```

and in my message controller

```
def create
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/javascript"
    attributes = params.require(:message).permit(:content, :sender_id, :sendee_id)
    @message = Message.create(attributes)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'messages/create.js.erb' }
    end
    $redis.publish('messages.create', @message.to_json)
  end

  def events
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
    redis = Redis.new
    redis.subscribe('messages.*') do |on|
      on.message do |pattern, event, data|
        response.stream.write("event: #{event}\n")
        response.stream.write("data: #{data}\n\n")
      end
    end
  rescue IOError
    logger.info "Stream closed"
  ensure
    redis.quit
    response.stream.close
  end
```

The problem is that first, nothing is logged in my console, and second I get numbers of random `ConnectionTimeoutError` errors. Some one hava an idea what's going on

Comment: Have you got the [redis server](http://redis.io/) running on your system?

Comment: Yes, it is running fine

Answer (score 2):

#### Pre-Reqs:

- Ruby 2.0.0+
- Rails 4.0.0+
- Redis
- Puma

---

#### Initializer:

Create a `redis.rb` initializer file in the `config/initializers` directory, globalizing an instance of `redis`. It's also a good idea to set up a `heartbeat` thread (Anything from 5 seconds to 5 minutes is okay, depending on your requirements):

```rb
$redis = Redis.new

heartbeat_thread = Thread.new do
  while true
    $redis.publish("heartbeat","thump")
    sleep 15.seconds
  end
end

at_exit do
  # not sure this is needed, but just in case
  heartbeat_thread.kill
  $redis.quit
end
```

---

#### Controller:

You need to add two methods to your `ChatController`, `pub` and `sub`. The role of `pub` is to publish chat events and messages to `redis`, and `sub` to subscribe to these events. It should look something like this:

```rb
class ChatController < ApplicationController
    include ActionController::Live

    skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
    end

    def pub
        $redis.publish 'chat_event', params[:chat_data].to_json
        render json: {}, status: 200
    end

    def sub
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"

        redis = Redis.new
        redis.subscribe(['chat_event']) do |on|
            on.message do |event, data|
                response.stream.write "event: #{event}\ndata: #{data}\n\n"
            end
        end
    rescue IOError
        logger.info "Stream Closed"
    ensure
        redis.quit
        response.stream.close
    end
end
```

In your `routes`, make ***pub*** a `POST` and ***sub*** a `GET`, and match the path to something like `/chat/publish` and `/chat/subscribe`.

---

#### Coffeescript / Javascript:

Assuming your actual webpage for the chat app is at `/chat`, you need to write some *Javascript* to actually send and receive chat messages.

For ease of understanding, let's suppose your webpage only has a textbox and a button. Hitting the button should publish the content of the textbox to the chat stream, we can do that using AJAX:

```
$('button#send').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax '/chat/publish',
        type: 'POST'
        data: {
            chat_data: {
                message: $("input#message").val(),
                timestamp: $.now()
            }
        }
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            console.log "Failed: " + textStatus 
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            console.log "Success: " + textStatus
```

Now, you need to be able to subscribe and receive the chat messages as well.  You need to use `EventSource` for this. Using *EventSource*, open a channel for SSE so that you can receive events, and use that data to update the view. In this example, we will only log them to the javascript console.

The code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
    source = new EventSource('/chat/subscribe')
    source.addEventListener 'chat_event', (e) ->
        console.log(e.data)
```

---

#### Enable Parallel Requests:

In your development environment, you'll have to enable parallel requests by adding these two lines to your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.preload_frameworks = true
config.allow_concurrency = true
```

Now fire up your browser, browse to `/chat` and see the magic. When you type a message and click the button, the message will be received by all instances of that webpage.

---

Well this is how you make a basic chat application in `rails` using `ActionController::Live` and `Redis`. The final code would obviously be very different depending on your requirements but this should get you started.

Some more resources you should check out:

- Tender Love Making - [Is it Live?](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html)
- Railscasts - [#401 - ActionController::Live](http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live)
- SitePoint - [Mini Chat with Rails and SSEs](http://www.sitepoint.com/mini-chat-rails-server-sent-events/)
- Github - [mohanraj-ramanujam / live-stream](https://github.com/mohanraj-ramanujam/live-stream)
- Thoughtbot - [Chat Example using SSEs](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/chat-example-app-using-server-sent-events)

Answer (score 1):

Although I've not used `redis` in this capacity (a mediator for "live" data), I managed to get this functionality working with `Pusher`

---

**Redis**

I don't understand how you're keeping the connection open between your app & Redis. You'll need some sort of web socket or concurrent-connection tech in place to handle the updates -- and to my knowledge, Redis does not handle this directly

If you look at [this example](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/chat-example-app-using-server-sent-events), it uses a server called [Goliath](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath) to handle the `asynchronous` connectivity:

> When tiny-chat connects to the server it sends a GET request to
>   /subscribe/everyone where everyone is the name of the channel and with
>   the “Accept” header set to text/event-stream. The streaming middleware
>   (above) receives this request and subscribes to a redis Pub/Sub
>   channel. Since Goliath is non-blocking multiple clients can be
>   listening for events without tying up a Heroku dyno. The payload of a
>   server sent event looks like this:

That basically uses Middleware to connect you to the redis server -- allowing you to receive updates as required

---

**Code**

Although I can't pinpoint any errors specifically, I can give you some code we're using (using [Pusher](http://pusher.com)):

```
    #config/initializers/pusher.rb
    Pusher.url = ENV["PUSHER_URL"]

    Pusher.app_id = ENV["PUSHER_APP_ID"]
    Pusher.key = ENV["PUSHER_KEY"]
    Pusher.secret = ENV["PUSHER_SECRET"]

    #app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
    def send_message
        id = params[:id]
        message = Message.find(id).broadcast!
        public_key = self.user.public_key
        Pusher['private-user-' + public_key].trigger('message_sent', {
            message: "Message Sent"
        })
    end

    #app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js" %>

    #app/assets/javascripts/application.js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    #Pusher
    pusher = new Pusher("************",
        cluster: 'eu'
    )

    channel = pusher.subscribe("private-user-#{gon.user}")
    channel.bind "multi_destroy", (data) ->
        alert data.message

    channel.bind "message_sent", (data) ->
        alert data.message
    });
```

Comment: Great thank you ;) I ll try `pusher` and I keep on debugging my thing

Comment: No problem - let me know if it helps. Having a third party websocket system really helps get the system in place, allowing you to iterate with your own functionality off the back of it